# "Bitter" versus "embittered"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, comparison

I have difficulty understanding the exact difference between these two adjectives, semantically. This is quote from a native English speaker:

> Parasite single? I guess an **embittered** parent wrote that one.

Why has the author written *embittered* instead of *bitter*? Is a different adjective used for a human and an object?

Comment: Anyway, besides the reasons given in answers, *an bitter parent* is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: What about a bitter parent or an embittered parent? A or an? Should I ask another question?

Comment: No additional question needed!  It's simple: if you want to say  “a *X* parent”, use bitter, not embittered; but if you want to say “an *X* parent”, vice versa.   (The smiley face for my previous comment was invisible, but here is one for this comment:)

Comment: Aha! I thought there is a different matter. It is obvious that before bitter you do not need an but a and vice versa! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A person who is **embittered** was *made* bitter, as opposed to being transiently bitter for some reason or another. The use of *embittered* in this sentence suggests that the parent has a particular ax to grind with whatever institution the speaker belongs to.

Answer (score 5):

I had to go to three dictionaries before I found one that gave credence to my understanding of the distinction between "bitter" and "embittered", but at [Cambridge's online dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/embitter?q=embittered), there is this definition:

> **embitter**, v.  to make someone feel angry and unhappy for a long time

So the difference between someone who is *bitter* and someone who is *embittered* is that the *bitter* person is bitter about some specific thing right now, while the *embittered* person is consistently bitter (and is likely to express their bitterness on a variety of matters), has probably been bitter for a long time, and shows no signs of relenting from their habitual bitterness.

Comment: Also, an *embittered* person has been ***made** bitter*; typically one writes that so-and-so has been *embittered **by*** some experience or treatment.

Comment: @StoneyB some prolonged experience or series of misfortunes is the usual context

Comment: @nathanhayfield The bitterness may be prolonged; the cause may be a single incident. [Adm. Fancourt] 'was embittered by being "bunged out" of the Navy (as he saw it), with just one month's notice.'

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the difference between the two terms is that we can use *embittered* for something for which we look and feel their effects; vice versa, we can use *bitter* with a  wider range.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but uncommon to describe a non-sentient thing as being embittered. Some recipes call for adding bitter flavors to a food or drink, so if a recipe called for adding lemons to a soup, you could say "That soup was embittered with lemon."